# El cálculo de números primos sólo devuelve el primer número

Tags: c++, algoritmos, bucles

Estoy haciendo un programa que calcula los números primos hasta un máximo (20 en el ejemplo) y devuelve los primos, el problema es que mi algoritmo solo devuelve un número.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void mostrar_primos(unsigned long int primos[],unsigned long int tam){
    unsigned long int i;
    for(i=0;i<tam;i++){
        cout<<primos[i]<<endl;
    }
}
int main(){ //1000000000
    cout<<"Empezando..."<<endl;
    unsigned long int maximo = 20; //numero maximo a buscar
    //criba secuencial
    unsigned long int* primos= new unsigned long int[maximo];//array dinamico
    //añadimos el 2 al array para poder saltarnos los pares
    primos[0] = 2;
    //recorremos los numeros impares desde el 3 hasta maximo
    unsigned long int posible_primo;//El numero actual para verificar si es primo
    unsigned long int pos;//auxiliar para recorrer el array
    int es_primo;
    for (posible_primo=3; posible_primo<maximo;posible_primo+=2){ // 3 5 7 9 11 ...
        /*comprobamos si es primo buscando si en el array hay algun
        numero primo que lo divida, pero solo hasta raiz de n*/
        unsigned long int ult_pos = (sizeof(primos)/sizeof(primos[0]));//ultima posicion del array
        es_primo = 1;//por defecto es primo
        for(pos=0;(pos<ult_pos) && (primos[pos]<sqrt(posible_primo));pos++){
            /*mientras el primo en la posicion pos sea menos que la raiz del 
            numero que queremos comprobar*/
            if(posible_primo%primos[pos]==0){
            //si es multiplo, entonces no es primo y salimos
                es_primo = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(es_primo==1){
            primos[ult_pos+1]=posible_primo;
        }
    }
    mostrar_primos(primos, (sizeof(primos)/sizeof(primos[0])));
    cout<<"Fin"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Mi programa devuelve:

> Empezando...
>
> 2
>
> Fin

No encuentro el fallo, tiene que ser que me haya hecho un lío con los bucles...

¿Alguien podría decirme dónde está el error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El bucle interno da una o dos vueltas antes de parar<sup>1</sup> con lo que nunca llegas a comprobar los números que te interesa, el motivo es que la expresión que calcula la última posición no hace lo que crees que hace:

```
unsigned long int ult_pos = (sizeof(primos)/sizeof(primos[0]));//ultima posicion del array
```

El tamaño de `primos` (`sizeof(primos)`) no es la cantidad de elementos de la formación si no el tamaño del puntero, que será 4 u 8 bytes (depende de la arquitectura de tu sistema), el tamaño de `primos[0]` será igualmente 4 u 8 bytes así que `ult_pos` siempre devolverá 1 o 2.

Tienes el mismo problema al intentar mostrar los datos<sup>1</sup> ya que muestras uno o dos elementos porque la división devuelve 1 o 2:

```
mostrar_primos(primos, (sizeof(primos)/sizeof(primos[0])));
//                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <--- Esta división siempre es 1 o 2.
```

#### Propuesta.

1. Estás trabajando en C++, deberías usar las herramientas del lenguaje.

   1. Usa el tipo `bool` no enteros para resultados lógicos.
   2. Declara los indizadores de bucle en el propio bucle.
   3. Usa contenedores, no formaciones dinámicas.
2. La operación `sqrt` es costosa, no la calcules en cada vuelta del bucle interno.
3. Deja respirar a tu código, apretujar las líneas y los operadores sólo hace que tu código sea más difícil de leer.

Siguiendo estos consejos tu código podría parecerse a:

```
int main(){
    cout << "Empezando...\n";
    auto maximo = 20ul; //numero maximo a buscar

    // Criba secuencial
    std::vector<int> primos{2}; // Añadimos el 2 al array para poder saltarnos los pares
    primos.reserve(maximo);

    for (auto posible_primo = 3ul; posible_primo < maximo; posible_primo += 2) {
        /* Comprobamos si es primo buscando si en el array hay algun
        numero primo que lo divida, pero solo hasta raiz de n. */
        const auto limite = sqrt(posible_primo);

        bool es_divisible = false;
        for (auto divisor : primos) {
            if (limite < divisor)
                break;
            if (es_divisible = !(posible_primo % divisor))
                break;
        }


        if (!es_divisible) {
            primos.push_back(posible_primo);
        }
    }

    for (auto primo : primos)
        std::cout << primo << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVNbbtswEPzXKTYpishJKwXun6UYKILeooCxomibCEUyfBhtAh@qZ@jB3CUpy498lAA/NNwdzgxXzJivG8YOh09CMRl6Di0b0G@XxQkQ2nnLcTjHdpx5bZdFEZxQG1A4cGeQcXC@b4pCKA8DClXO3gugxXTw0LZw@2Mw/A1Vr6uq@qlum3SKwWsq/yUGDU8wfwyygbpWYeB2whG64BjaInXUNTxb0SE4zgJXTKBMON2@WGRtLWlYgrHU7N7n@8gI3//@wT4CwCXMASWgtfgbDFoEo3tuwaH0aBWVSNp0wF1izkQVfXK742VWNWuynLW2UCYXRjvRSb5K5WTmW/RyCbajpWv8gazPIOeVPN7Dsx6M1R1GxU4Ad1lGjoJCTKCKZrKPLW2Um6AmkjHE3PYaOLmCXuxEj1/AxBOnCdmi8wgWxRvQ46oK7uuJgWnlfH4iKQbhOblyr9aXF@qPScTVaS1J6yrek0qoY43S8WYqOQWWiuhrMSZ8nkBcYg3leG97LJ5dVKQraT5fmg@NVyJuLjXD54nwv4z74uQvMt@cU19rHmfFBLdddchePkR1Yh25r4YoqZsSmcrTdB9/pXGYWriDuzF8y32wCh6bYn84/AM)</kbd>.

---

<sup>1</sup>Cosa de la que te habrías dado cuenta si hubieses depurado el código.

Comment: Pues no consigo hacer funcionar el debugger, por eso no lo pude depurar. No obstante, encontré una web online que me permitía depurarlo y encontré ese error.

Comment: @XBoss ¿Qué ide estás usando?

Comment: Por cierto, muchas gracias, tu código es mucho más óptimo que el mío, rabia no haber caido en tu comentario sobre sqrt. Utilizo VSCode, pero lo he intentado con muchos otros y tengo tanto MinGW como cygwin64 instalado de todas las pruebas que he hecho.

Comment: He creado una sala donde me gustaría poder preguntarte algunas dudas sobre el algoritmo que has puesto, para no saturar los comentarios: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99427/paperbirdmaster

¿Podrías entrar?