# Problema con números primos

Tags: java

A continuación detallo el planteamiento del problema.

-Leer un número entero de dos dígitos y determinar si es primo y además si es negativo.

El código que he realizado funciona correctamente, pero al ingresar por teclado un número múltiplo de 5 el programa lo reconoce como número primo y no comprendo el porque, adicional el programa deber ser realizado solo con la sentencia IF. Por tal motivo pido  ayuda, una guia para resolver este problema. De antemano las gracias infinitas.

```
package algoritmo7;

import java.util.Scanner;



 public class ejercicio7 {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
       
          Scanner obj=new Scanner (System.in);
        
            
            int num=0;
        System.out.println("ingresar numero");
        num=obj.nextInt();
        
        if (num>0) {
            if (num>9 && num<100) 
            {
              
                    if (num%2==0)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Numeor positivo  no primo");
                    }else
                        System.out.println("Numero positivo   primo");
            }else
                System.out.println("Ingresar numero de 2 digitos");
        }else
            if (num>-100 && num<-9) {
           
                    if (num%2==0) 
                    {
                        System.out.println("Numeor negativo no  primo");
                    }else
                        System.out.println("Numero negativo   primo");
            }else
                System.out.println("Ingresar numero de 2 digitos");
            
  
    }
}
```

Comment: Por cierto, los números primos, por definición no pueden ser negativos.

Comment: Hacerlo solo con if no esta bien, te hace falta también utilizar ciclos for

Comment: SOes ya tiene mucho contenido relacionado con números primos [como este](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/298042/182188) por ejemplo. Revisalo a ver si te ayuda a salir de dudas

Comment: Saludos  estimados, muchas gracias por sus comentarios, bendiciones !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según la lógica de tu programa num % 2  == 0 con eso solo estás comprobando si es par o impar. Deberías hacer la misma comprobación con los números primos: 3,5,7. Y los negativos no son primos.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    
    public class Test {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
    
            Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    
            int num = 0;
            System.out.println("ingresar numero");
            num = obj.nextInt();
    
            if (num > 0) {
                if (num > 9 && num < 100) {
    
                    if (num % 2 == 0 || num % 3 == 0 || num % 5 == 0 || num % 7 == 0 ) {
                        System.out.println("Numeor positivo  no primo");
                    } else
                        System.out.println("Numero positivo   primo");
                } else
                    System.out.println("Ingresar numero de 2 digitos");
            } else if (num > -100 && num < -9) {
    
                System.out.println("Numero negativo");
    
            } else
                System.out.println("Ingresar numero de 2 digitos");
    
    
        }
    }
```

**Código refactorizado**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int num = 0;

        System.out.println("ingresar numero");
        num = obj.nextInt();

        if (Math.abs(num) >= 10) {

            if (num <= 0) System.out.println("Numero negativo");

            else if (num % 2 == 0 || num % 3 == 0 || num % 5 == 0 || num % 7 == 0 ) {
                System.out.println("Numero no primo");
            } else
                System.out.println("Numero no primo");

        } else
            System.out.println("Ingresar numero de 2 digitos");


    }
}
```

Comment: te agradezco por revolver mi problema tenia varias horas sin entenderlo, ahora desde tu lógica he comprendido perfectamente, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Amigo recuerda que un numero es primo si solo es divisible entre 1 y el mismo numero
yo lo hice de esta forma, espero te sea de utilidad
Recuerda lo que dijeron los demás compañeros que un numero primo tiene que ser positivo...
Hice unas correcciones, espero te funcione

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ejercicio {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   
Scanner obj=new Scanner (System.in);
    
        
    int num=0;
System.out.println("Nota: Debe ingresar un numero de dos digitos");
    System.out.println("Ingresar numero");
    num=obj.nextInt();
    
    if ((num>9 && num<100) || (num>-100 && num<-9)) {
        if (num<=0)
    System.out.println("Numero Negativo");
        else if(num%2==0 || num%3==0 || num%5==0  || num%7==0)
    System.out.println("Numero Positivo No Primo");
        else
            System.out.println("Numero Positivo Primo");
    }else
        System.out.println("Error! Debe ingresar un numero de 2 digitos");
        

}
```

}

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda, es verdad, no tuve claro el objetivo del problema trabajare en eso, saludos.

Comment: @waldo esta no es una solución. Es igual a la pregunta inicial, solo evalúa si un número es par o impar `num%2!=0`.

Comment: @Lobos Amigo primero evalua si el numero es divisible entre 1 y el mismo, si lo es y a la vez ese numero al dividirlo entre dos su residuo es diferente de cero resulta que es primo

Comment: Al evaluar primero si es divisible entre el y 1 obtenemos que puede ser primo pero para que en realidad se cumpla la condicion, este también no tiene que ser divisible entre 2...

Comment: @CarlosDuarte Todos los números son divisibles entre la unidad y ellos mismos por lo tanto esas condiciones están de más. Quedando solamente `num  % 2 !=  0`. Eso nos dice que si no es divisible entre 2 será primo. Y que tal si es divisible entre 3? o 5? por ejemplo el número 15?

Comment: @Lobos tienes razon amigo, deja lo corrijo, igual con tu programa tengo una duda, cuanto el numero es 11, debería ser primo cierto?

Comment: @waldo lee los comentarios amigo, resulta que me he equivocado en algo

Comment: @Lobos ya lo he corregido, ahora si funciona?

Comment: @CarlosDuarte sí esa es la lógica correcta. Y sí el 11 debe ser primo.

Comment: @CarlosDuarte Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, saludos.

Comment: @Lobos Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, saludos.

Comment: Les comento que gracias a su aporte y ayudarme a comprender como funciona, he podido realizar los 20 ejercicios que tenia de # primos.

Comment: que bueno bro... suerte en tus trabajo, échale ganas...